# How to implement removing HTTP referer in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a small web app written in Python Flask which has links to third-party web site. However, I don't want my site to be shown in referer when user go to that site via these links. I currently use some anonymous service for removing referer, but was wondering how can I implement referer removing by my own in Flask? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Referer is added by the browser to the new HTTP request, so there's not much you can do regardless of the framework. Besides, this whole goal does look slightly suspicious.

Comment: I take the first part back: there is [`rel=noreferrer`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-noreferrer) attribute in HTML5.